# Using regular expression replacement in PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

`ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address"` returns something like this:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.50
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.112.1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.208.1
```

Say I wanted to replace "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :" with the empty string using [-replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#regular-expressions-substitutions). How would I do that? Here's what I tried:

```
ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address" -replace "IPv4 Address. . .",""
```

That gave me the following error:

```
Select-String : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'.
At line:1 char:41
+ ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address" -replace "IPv4 Address. . .", ...
+                                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-String], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectStringCommand
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the close vote here, you stated what you want, what you tried, and the issue. Seems like you did everything that SU requires. I adjusted the title a little bit in case that's the reason someone voted to close. Otherwise seems like someone did something they shouldn't have with that vote.

Comment: since you are using PoSh, why don't use _use powershell_? this >>> `(Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object AddressFamily -eq ipv4).IPAddress` <<< seems to get the same info while using just powershell.

Comment: duplicate from same use >>> regex - how to use regular expression replacement in PowerShell - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754706/how-to-use-regular-expression-replacement-in-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd rewrite it to perform the [`-replace`](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) operation using a different syntax. This way it does not have to look for a parameter with the [`Select-String`](https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html) function.

As there error indicates: `Select-String : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'replace'` this is exactly the problem—`Select-String` does not have a `-Replace` parameter.

### Valid Syntaxes

```
(ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address") -replace "IPv4 Address. . .",""
```

Or

```
(ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address").Tostring().Replace("IPv4 Address. . .","")
```

Or save the first part of the command to a variable and then run the **replace** operation

```
$s = ipconfig | Select-String "IPv4 Address"
$s -replace "IPv4 Address. . .",""
```

### Output

```
. . . . . . . . : X.X.X.X
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [Select-String](https://ss64.com/ps/select-string.html)